# Java Swing - Scrollable Panel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jscrollpane

I am trying to create a scrollable panel using swing. But as I am new to swing, I am failing to do so. In my code nothing shows up inside the *jScrollablePane*.

I have created a *jframe* and put a *jScrollablePane* inside it. And I created a class called **UIElement** that extends *jPanel* which includes a components section, and child section. Child sections consist of other **UIElement**s.

- All the **UIElements** should be placed under the previous **UIElement**. Like a vertical list.
- The **childs** should be placed under the **components**.
- Childs section cannot scroll and its height is fixed to total of the child UIElements' height.
- The **components** has fixed height of 40. While the width could extend with its container.
- The **spacer**'s width should be fixed to 40.
- Except from **spacer**, everything's width is dynamic.
- A **UIElement**'s could have zero or more children.

Here is some picture example, don't forget: width is dynamic.

[image]

And here is the code:

```
public static void scrollable(String title) {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500,GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds().height);

    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    mainPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    mainPanel.add(new UIElement());

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(mainPanel,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

    //Display the window.
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

And here is the **UIElement** class:

```
public abstract class UIElement extends JPanel {
    public static final int DESIREDHEIGHT = 40;

    JPanel componentsPanel, childPanel;

    public UIElement () {
        super();
        this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        // componentsPanel
        componentsPanel = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                Dimension d = super.getPreferredSize();
                d.setSize(d.getWidth(),DESIREDHEIGHT);
                return d;
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
                Dimension d = super.getMaximumSize();
                d.setSize(d.getWidth(),DESIREDHEIGHT);
                return d;
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
                Dimension d = super.getPreferredSize();
                d.setSize(d.getWidth(),DESIREDHEIGHT);
                return d;
            }
        };
        componentsPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(componentsPanel,BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        componentsPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        this.add(componentsPanel);

        // child panel
        childPanel = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                float height = 0;
                for (Component c: super.getComponents())
                    height += c.getPreferredSize().height;
                Dimension d = super.getPreferredSize();
                d.setSize(d.getWidth(),height);
                return d;
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
                float height = 0;
                for (Component c: super.getComponents())
                    height += c.getMaximumSize().height;
                Dimension d = super.getMaximumSize();
                d.setSize(d.getWidth(),height);
                return d;
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
                float height = 0;
                for (Component c: super.getComponents())
                    height += c.getMinimumSize().height;
                Dimension d = super.getMinimumSize();
                d.setSize(d.getWidth(),height);
                return d;
            }
        };
        childPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(childPanel,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        childPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);

        // parent for childPanel and spacer
        JPanel childParent = new JPanel();
        childParent.setLayout(new BoxLayout(childParent,BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

        // spacer
        JPanel spacer = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(DESIREDHEIGHT,DESIREDHEIGHT);
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
                return new Dimension(DESIREDHEIGHT,DESIREDHEIGHT);
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
                return new Dimension(DESIREDHEIGHT,DESIREDHEIGHT);
            }
        };
        spacer.setBackground(Color.RED);
        childParent.add(spacer);
        // add the childPanel later
        childParent.add(childPanel);
    }


    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        Dimension c = componentsPanel.getPreferredSize();
        Dimension d = childPanel.getPreferredSize();
        return new Dimension(c.width, c.height + d.height);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
        Dimension c = componentsPanel.getMaximumSize();
        Dimension d = childPanel.getMaximumSize();
        return new Dimension(c.width, c.height + d.height);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
        Dimension c = componentsPanel.getMinimumSize();
        Dimension d = childPanel.getMinimumSize();
        return new Dimension(c.width, c.height + d.height);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't override `getPreferredSize()` (or maximum/minim sizes) of the panels.

Each panel will determine its preferred size based on the layout manager of the panel and the components added to the panel.

That is if a panel uses a layout manager, there is no need to override those methods. You only need to override the `getPreferredSize()` methods for a custom component that has no layout manager. In Swing terms this would be a JButton, JTextField, JLabel etc.

So you if are creating a custom component then you set the size. If you just use a component as a container with a layout manager to hold other components then you don't calculate the size.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/problems.html - search for the word "fix"

Comment: erased all overrides for the getPreferredSize() method, did not work

Comment: @ossobuko, you missed my point about the "custom components" needing to have a proper size defined. If all you are using are JPanels then yes the custom panel at the bottom of the hierarchy needs the proper size. The panels in the middle of the hierarchy which appear to me to be using a BoxLayout, should NOT be overriding the size calculations.

Comment: The problem was all the panels were empty. Anyways, you are correct about onPreferredSize(), but that was not the problem.

Comment: @ossobuko, it was "a problem" that would have led to inconsistent results if not fixed. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.